# Confused about interfaces and implementation

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

The case is very simple, I have this interface

```
public interface IHasNext
{
    IHasNext NextItem { get; set; }
}
```

and then I attempt to implement it like so:

```
public class Item : IHasNext
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    Item NextItem { get; set; }
}
```

but this won't work because the property NextItem of the implementation is not of the same type (even if the type implements the interface). So could someone kindly explain me the reason for this not working, when you can quite liberally swap types for interfaces they implement even as type parameters (at least on IEnumerable and IQueryable).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
public class BadItem : IHasNext
{
    public IHasNext { get; set; }
}
```

Now:

```
IHasNext item = new Item();
item.NextItem = new BadItem();
```

That's perfectly valid... but what would you expect it to do on the `Item` class? Its `NextItem` property is of type `Item`, so it doesn't know what to do with a `BadItem`...

Basically, doing this is unsafe.

You may want to make your interface generic:

```
public interface IHasNext<T> where T : IHasNext<T>
{
    T NextItem { get; set; }
}

public class Item : IHasNext<Item>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    IHasNext<Item> NextItem { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense indeed, thanks for the clear clarification!

Answer (score 0):

The interface states that the property must be of type `IHasNext`, your code should be:

```
public class Item : IHasNext
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    IHasNext NextItem { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you implementing it as:

```
 public class Item : IHasNext
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    IHasNext NextItem { get; set; }
 }
```

? This interface could be on any class that implements `IHasNext`.

But better still is to make it generic

```
public interface IHasNext<T>
{
    T NextItem { get; set; }
}

 public class Item : IHasNext<Item>
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    Item NextItem { get; set; }
 }
```